# What is the best way to mock ajax response with angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, mocking

I have a java back-end that support all of the calls from the UI.

For the UI Phase i'm using nodeJS in order to run it and check that everything is working at localhost:4200, when need to publish it to the tomcat server, copying the dist folder to the webapp at tomcat then the application is available at localhost:8080.

The questions is if there is a simple and easy way while running the UI side on nodeJS to mock all of the response to the ajax call that been made in the UI and when publishing the dist folder to the tomcat it will be transperant and will work with the server side.

I think that its kind of setting up an additional server in nodeJS and map all of the calls and return the static json from there. or there is any other easy way?

Answer (score 0):

```
         "scripts": {
        "start": "start npm run start-server && gulp serve",
        "start-server": "node src/server/app.js",
        "start-client": "ng serve",
        "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
        "e2e": "protractor"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
        "express": "^4.14.0"
        }
```

create server.js file in project folder and add below code

```
        var express = require("express");
        var app = express();
        var router = require('express').Router();
        var data = require('./server/api/users/data.json');

       app.get("/", function(req, res) {
       res.send(data)
       });

    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port, function() {
      console.log("Listening on " + port);
    });
```

Create a folder for mock data naming server->api->users->data.json and put the below data

```
    [{
    "name":"Hello"
    },
    {
     "name":"World"
    }]
```

In order to use mock data, you need to install express server. Add above lines in your package.json and run command npm install and once install, use npm start. npm start will start your gulp serve(or use appropriate cmd as per server installed) and express server both.

Comment: How do I use the express server in order to response the requests?

Comment: where is the server.js file need to be placed? where is the reference to this file in order to run it in the server? can you make sure that all the info is correct and exist?

Comment: server.js file will be placed in project root folder and I have tested this in my local machine. Lets try on this and let me know, if you find any issue

Comment: "start-server": "node src/server/app.js" what is the app.js stands for? should i create it?

Comment: No Need..That is only applicable, if you put a command start-server. But you just need to put npm start.

Comment: Did you try on this?

Comment: npm start running start-server start server looking for ser/server/app.js, in case you dont have this file, it wont work, there for the file is required, open a new project and try it.

Comment: Thats shows you didnt tried yet. No issues for your doubts, you can go through with this link [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start). You can remove scripts object from package.json. Npm start takes server.js file

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\WebstormProjects\TestsOnly\src\server\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

as i said, there is no app.js , should i create it?

Comment: was trying the above on a clean project.